# Django template variable in style tag

Tags: django

Can't seem to get a variable percentage width output in my Django tag.

```
            {% with "width: "|add:percent|add:"%" as percent_style %}
            <div class="percentile" style={% include percent_style %} />
            {% endwith %}
```

What am i doing wrong here? I get this error

> django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: %

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `include` tag which trying to find template named `percent_style` you should simple use `{{ percent_style }}`:

```
{% with "width: "|add:percent|add:"%" as percent_style %}
<div class="percentile" style="{{ percent_style }}" />
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: I see the html output of that is `style="%"`

Comment: @AlxVallejo try to add quotes: `"{{ percent_style }}"`. It should work. What is `percent` variable value?

Comment: @AlxVallejo `percent` should be a string. You need to convert it to string in view.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be easy to do, instead of trying to `include`, just use the variable concatenated with the percent `%` sign. You don't need to use `{% with %} {% endwith %}`

```
<div class="percentile" style="width:{{ percent }}%" />
```